# How to integrate Scala into core Android platform?

Tags: android, scala, dalvik, jvm-languages

I am interested in integrating Scala (or some other non-Java JVM-language) into the android platform. I am not referring to writing an android application with Scala, that I did early early on, but actually hooking into the build process that builds the android platform source tree. I imagine this will be a matter of hooking into the makefiles and such. Does anyone have insight into this?

**What I have so far:**
The platform source treefrom git://android.git.kernel.org/platform/manifest.git built in its virgin form, guided by "[Download and build the Google Android][1]"

- build/core/combo/scalac.mk # Configures scala compiler related variables, included by config.mk
- Added definitions in build/core/definitions.mk for an all-subdir-scala-files and an all-scala-files-under
- Added definition in definitions.mk to build scala files such that they are included in the package

**What's left:**

- Include scala-library.jar
- Ensure changes to -bootclasspath has not broken anything
- Figure out how to handle case where scala classes depend on java classes and visa versa
- Major cleanup of code
- Testing!
- Figure out what to do (other than just posting them here) with the changes I've made

Looks like I'm **almost there!!!**

**Some notes from the past**

Latest: I have found where the Java source files are compiled! In definitions.mk, see 'define transform-java-to-classes.jar'. The latest idea is to write a transform-scala-to-classes definition and then have it store those classes in the directly that gets packaged. I will call transform-scala-to-class right before this step in transform-java-to-classes.jar. Support for eclipse and cygwin will for now be dropped as it clutters up the code with workarounds and therefore increases my chances of failure.

The build process starts out by the root Makefile running build/core/main.mk
build/core/main.mk includes build/core/config.mk which includes build/core/combo/javac.mk which sets HOST_JAVAC, TARGET_JAVAC, and COMMON_JAVAC. COMMON_JAVAC is the "Java compiler command with common arguments," by the look of it the other two variables get these values by default, unless in a special environment (openjdk or eclipse). COMMON_JAVAC is not used outside this file. The other two are only used in build/core/definitions.mk.

build/core/java_library.mk (included by config.mk) seems to only be concerned with building jars. This is out of the scope of us caring. Any interaction with jars presupposes class files which presuppose that we were already successful in building our scala files.

There are checks in main.mk regarding the version of java. We will ignore these and assume that our version of scala is compatible. Right now (in combo/scalac.mk) I am using the same --target arg used in javac.mk. This should perhaps be stored in a variable.

main.mk also includes build/core/definitions.mk which in turns defines some useful functions. The one we care about here is all-java-files-under and all-subdir-java-files. The latter is used in Android.mk files to find java files. The former is used in the implementation of the latter. I will write Scala equivalents of them.

To figure out how the build process works, I am now running make with -n and others. I got this idea from the stackoverflow article "[Tool for debugging makefiles][2]". I am also investigating debugging with remake.

build/core/{config.mk, definitions.mk} gives us light as to which make files/commands are used to do what.

As a possible way of hacking in support on a per project bases, additional code could most likely be added to the project's Android.mk file. From platform/build/core/build-system.html we read "Android.mk is the standard name for the makefile fragments that control the building of a given module. Only the top directory should have a file named "Makefile"." You could create a new target like "scala-build" and run that (make PackageName scala-build) before the final make. One could perhaps also hide it sneakily in a variable assignment, mitigating the need for a target to be called explicitly.

Another way (far far more hackish) is to hijack the command being used for javac. This is set in build/core/combo/javac.mk. Your project's Android.mk will have to include *.scala files in LOCAL_SRC_FILES along with the *.java files.

Comment: I would ask about this on the android building mailing list. 
https://groups.google.com/group/android-building

Answer (score 8):

Guys on reddit say, there's a tutorial on integration Scala into Android with ant [here](http://www.tylerlesmann.com/2009/dec/04/integrating-scala-android-ant/).

Comment: @Octoberdan if you could notify this thread of your progress, that would have been really cool.

Comment: I was away for the weekend, but just got back. I wont have time to give it a go until tomorrow. I will certainly let you know!

Comment: Actually, this was not what I was looking for. I was looking for integrating it into the build system of the platform itself. Thank you anyways!